# External users unable to search directory

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-permissions, external-sharing

I am new to SharePoint so might have missed something obvious.

I have shared a specific folder with an external user. When I search from within my own account I am able to see results from within the shared folder however, if my external user does the same they get no results.

The external users have read and edit permissions for docs on the site, am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are these external users members of AD guest users? My testing shows that search only works for such users. Here's a question I have created https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310740/sharepoint-online-search-behaviour-with-sharing-link-sharing-or-direct-access