# SharePoint online search behaviour with sharing (link sharing or direct access) via AD guest vs external user

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search, external-sharing, sharing

I'm using sharpeoint online and testing the following on a document library folder.

Testing search functionality for following users:

1. Internal AD users
2. AD guest users
3. External users

When I share folders with the above via link share or direct access, then I'm observing that only internal AD users and AD guest users are able to search the documents.

External users who have the folder shared via link sharing cannot search. Is this expected?

Comment: I think, yes. They can access the shared folders/files only via the shared link.

Comment: This question is specifically about ability to search. So I'm not sure what you mean by `I think, yes.`

Comment: `Is this expected?` - I think, yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the behavior is expected:

- SharePoint Online’s search capabilities are not available to external users by default.
- External users who have access to a folder via link sharing will not be able to use the search function.
- There is a workaround to enable the search center for external users by configuring the search settings: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-external-users-and-search/69d09fe7-9c65-4358-85d5-d97597c1102d